# ¿Como dar formato personalizado a un String C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Teniendo un string así:

```
String texto = "123456890";
```

Como puedo hacer que la salida en pantalla se vea así:

```
(123)4567890
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empleando el método [String.format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)  de la clase [String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string)

```
String texto = "123456890";
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:(###) ######}", Convert.ToInt64(texto));
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! =D